# Capture when disabled property is changed (IE8 compatible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Is there any simple way to capture an event when an element disabled property (or other css properties) is changed? I know there is **MutationObservers**, but it seems is not supported by IE8-IE9. I need to use a plugin?

**Actual MutationObservers compatibility**:

```
Chrome:  18-16
Firefox: 14
IE:      11
Opera:   15
Fafari   6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the DOM L3 Event specification, MutationOberservers were introduced with DOM4 Events to [replace MutationEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-mutationevent-events) originally defined by DOM L3 events.  (It appears there were inconsistences in the way different browsers implemented support.)

The [IE Compatibility Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265032(v=vs.85).aspx) has more details on this change, including [migration details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265032(v=vs.85).aspx).

So you might be able to use [MutationEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974346(v=vs.85).aspx) for IE9 and IE10; however, they were not supported in IE8.  [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation) suggests the [HTML Web Components polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) as a possible alternative.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance